# How to properly exit javaFX Platform.runLater

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, exit, platform

The code below doest not exit properly when I close the application. I believe the issue is where do i exactly call the system.exit and platform.exit....

```
hour_Label.textProperty().bind(hour);
minute_Label.textProperty().bind(minute);
second_Label.textProperty().bind(second);

new Thread(() -> 
{    
    for (;;) 
    {                 
        try 
        { 
            final SimpleDateFormat simpledate_hour = new SimpleDateFormat("h");
            final SimpleDateFormat simpledate_minute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
            final SimpleDateFormat simpledate_second = new SimpleDateFormat("s");
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() 
                {
                    hour.set(simpledate_hour.format(new Date()));
                    minute.set(simpledate_minute.format(new Date()));
                    second.set(simpledate_second.format(new Date())); 
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(200);                
        }
        catch (Exception e){logger.warn("Unexpected error", e); Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); Platform.exit(); System.exit(0);}
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not exit properly?"

Comment: I have to force quit the app on OS X when I close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use threads! Use a `Timeline` instead:

```
Timeline clock = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), evt -> {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        hour.set(String.format("%d", now.getHour()));            
        minute.set(String.format("%02d", now.getMinute()));            
        second.set(String.format("%d", now.getSecond()));            
    }),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
);
clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
clock.play();
```

As a `Timeline` is run by the FX Application Thread, you don't need any synchronization via `Platform.runLater(...)`. Apart from that, you can start and stop the timeline as desired, and it automatically terminates when the FX Application Thread stops.

Answer (score 4):

Make your thread a [daemon thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-).

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

You also need to let the thread know that it should exit.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Sleeper extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label time = new Label();

        AtomicBoolean shuttingDown = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!shuttingDown.get() && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> time.setText(new Date().toString()));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1_000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(event -> {
            shuttingDown.set(true);
            thread.interrupt();
            Platform.exit();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(time), 240, 40));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

You don't need to invoke Platform.exit() or System.exit(0) in an exception handler of your thread.

You may find it more convenient to use a JavaFX [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).  The task documentation explains methods of canceling a task.

But really, I wouldn't advise using another thread at all for your example, instead use a Timeline as exemplified in Sergey's five second wonder in his answer to: [JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task).